# ios UITextView when keyBoard Hidden,text also retain my view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextview

I add `UITextView` to `UIToolBar`.
and when I finish my `UITextView`, and keyboard was hidden, but the text also retain my view.

when I start my `UITextView`, photo link:

[image]

when I finish my `UITextView`,photo link:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to the animate the view upside when keyboard is visible . like :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
CGRect rect=self.view.frame;
rect.origin.y=rect.origin.y-100;
self.view.frame=rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

you can adjust that 100 value as per your requirement . Then do the reverse process when the key is disappeared.

Comment: YES, i was to do so,bu i setAnimationDuration is 0.3

Comment: In wich method are you putting this? please add some breakpoints

Comment: i setAnimationDuration is 0.5,and it Looks a lot better

Comment: but if you set it 0.3 then also it should not matter actually . you cant experience the animation in that case .But you can accept answer if this helps you

Comment: help me so mush!! Thanks! and i found maybe add a Progress is best,Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

        CGRect frame = textInputView.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= kbSize.height;
        textInputView.frame = frame;

        frame = bubbleTable.frame;
        frame.size.height -= kbSize.height;
        bubbleTable.frame = frame;
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{

        CGRect frame = textInputView.frame;
        frame.origin.y += kbSize.height;
        textInputView.frame = frame;

        frame = bubbleTable.frame;
        frame.size.height += kbSize.height;
        bubbleTable.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```